# how to get nearest 20 locations using php based on current user location

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

I have the following tables

```
1. user table containing 
userid  lastlatitude  lastlongitude  lastlocation
---------------------------------------------------
 1       38.555605      -121.468926     California
 2        30.4518         -84.27277       Florida
2. locations table containing
location_id  latitude  longitude location_name   
----------------------------------------------------
  1      38.7547          -140.7878892622     abc
  2.     40.7547         -111.895672622  New asdsd
  3      41.xxx           xxxxxxxx         xxxxxx
```

i need to get the following output:
if i pass users lat and long i should get nearest 20 locations that are stored in my locations table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you would need to calculate the distance. Please check out http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL if this helps.

EDITED:

As in http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL, the query below might fit your requirement:

```
set @orig_lat=122.4058;  // pass users lat
set @orig_lon=37.7907;   // pass users long

SELECT *,

3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -
abs( 
dest.latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( 
abs
(dest.latitude) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.longitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))

as distance FROM locations dest ORDER BY distance limit 20;
```

Comment: i calculated distance. but i think its not good idea to store  the distance in table, as user migrates from one place to another every time we need to calculate the distance and update the table

Comment: Yes. I do agree. Please check out my edited answer if it works. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it wont suit my table structure. i hope this answer would help me in the next view... :)